# How to NOT keep logical logs in neo4j?

Tags: java, performance, neo4j

We do something as follows for an embedded Neo4j (1.9.2) application"

```
        Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
        config.put("use_memory_mapped_buffers", "true");
        config.put("keep_logical_logs", "false");

        graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
                .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(getActiveGraphDirectory())
                .setConfig(config).newGraphDatabase();
```

However, we are seeing files like nioneo_logical.log.v20 etc. 
At times these files grow very large so we are not interested in keeping them. We understand we won't be able to backup/restore but we have different ways of implementing HA.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem as though setting it to false only keeps the most recent log. From their documentation:

```
# Will keep only the most recent non-empty log
keep_logical_logs=false
```

Could you try setting the disk threshold to something low? Something like `keep_logical_logs = 0M size`

Comment: It seems =false is doing the job of only keeping the recent logs and we are fine with that for now